# How to determine percent contribution to classification in logistic regression?

Tags: mathematics, machine-learning, statistics

I'm trying to understand the contribution of each feature towards a specific classification.  Let's say I have clients as my data and their features are income, debt and age.  We're trying to predict whether they will default on some loan.  client 1 has been classified as they will default with probability 95%.  I want to determine how much each feature has contributed to this client's classification result with the underlying goal of showing that income primarily drove client 1's default classification and debt primarily drove client 2's default classification for example.

Logistic regression is defined as

[image: logistic]

A single client's classification is

[image: logit single]

I want to understand how much each feature (b_i) has contributed but we can't split apart the features and calculate their portion of the probability unless we get rid of the exponential.  We can look to the contribution to log odds though

[image: logodds]

but now the terms on the right hand side can be positive or negative so I cannot say b_0 contributes 20% of the classification result for example.

[image: linear combo]

this seems like a simple question but the answer isn't clear.  The log odds are above.  If we sum up -2, -0.4 and 0.3 and solve for p we get the probability of default.  We know that the largest number contributes the most to this classification but how do I compare 0.3's contribution to the -2 and -0.4?